# Is it safe to create multiple PATHs for various programs that require a path when using certain coding programs?

Tags: path, system

When I started with python, it told me to create a PATH in my system environment. 
But now, im getting into Java and C++ with other programs. The setup wants me to create a path for those.
Will creating a new PATH delete previous paths for other programs?
Im not sure how this works.

I am using windows7

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> Im not sure how this works.

Depending on your operating system environment there's a delimiter to set multiple paths in the `PATH` variable that controls where the system should lookup for executable programs.

At windows the delimiter is `;`, on unix/linux like OSs the delimiter is `:`.

So the `PATH` variable value should look like

```
PATH = "/usr/bin:/home/bin:<...>"
```

at a unix/linux like OS.

To prevent overwriting the old values, you can set it like

```
PATH = "$PATH:/some_new_path"
```